# EmberData unloadAll doesn't work on IE8. Works on Chrome/FireFox

Tags: javascript, ember.js, internet-explorer-8, ember-data, ember-cli

Thanks in advance for the help !

I am having a problem refreshing my model on IE8. (Works on Chrome Chrome and Firefox)
I run this code to refresh my model with a request to the database using my adapter. Through this command I am unloading the data of the model and reloading it again to display it to the user:

```
var type = self.controller.get('model').type;

this.controller.get('model').get('store').unloadAll(type);
this.controller.get('model').get('store').fetchAll(type);
```

No Javascript errors. I have looked for a solution but not a clue about it. Any idea?

Thanks !

EDIT : I got a solution. IE8 was caching my fetchAll() method from Ember Data. The solution was to manually set on the response header that I didn't want Cache:

Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 31 Mar 2015 09:35:48 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Problably this is because you are directly accessing the type and ie8 doesn't support computed properties. Can you check using proper Ember getters?

```
var type = self.controller.get('model.type');

this.controller.get('model').get('store').unloadAll(type);
this.controller.get('model').get('store').fetchAll(type);
```

You can also try access controllers like this:
    var type = self.get('controller.model.type');

```
this.get('controller.model.store').unloadAll(type);
this.get('controller.model.store').get('store').fetchAll(type);
```